# Establishing session for Acumatica web services

Tags: web-services, erp, acumatica

Establishing session for Acumatica web services
I have a requirement where a session is to be established using web services, and then use that session to perform subsequent actions.  E.g. Creating SOOrder and Shipment using web services using a previously created session/token.

```
SOOrder.Screen content = new SOOrder.Screen();
content.Url = InstanceUrl + “/Soap/SO301000.asmx";
content.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
SOOrder.LoginResult lresult= content.Login(Username, password);
```

Using this, I have already obtained a session in lresult.Session.

Now, I would like to use this session in below shipmentcontent without calling login again.

```
SOShipment.Screen shipmentcontent = new SOShipment.Screen();
shipmentcontent.Url = InstanceUrl + "(W(3))/Soap/SO302000.asmx";
shipmentcontent.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
shipmentcontent.Login(Username, password);
```

Answer (score 0):

By package various screens in Web Services (SM.20.70.40) found under System -> Integration -> Configure -> Web Services you create a single end-point for all these screens.  Consume this service end-point in you app, login only once and call out to all those screens.

thnx

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you corectly you want to persist your login connection between different actions in Acumatia. In order to achieve this, I used the following approach:

1. Create graph:

   public class Importer : PXGraph
       {
       }
2. Inside graph created following code:

   public string GetHostUrl()
               {
                   var nextIndex = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().IndexOf("/", 7,   StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1;
                   var urlStart = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().IndexOf("/", nextIndex + 1, StringComparison.Ordinal);
                   var url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().Substring(0, urlStart);
                   return url;
               }

   ```
           public Screen Screen
           {
               get
               {
                   var context = new Screen
                   {
                       CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
                       AllowAutoRedirect = true,
                       EnableDecompression = true,
                       Timeout = 1000000
                   };
                   var nextIndex = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().IndexOf("/", 7,        StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1;
                   var urlStart = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().IndexOf("/", nextIndex + 1, StringComparison.Ordinal);
                   context.Url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().Substring(0, urlStart) + "/Soap/IMPORTET.asmx";

                   return context;
               }
           }
   ```

and then between different screens shared context of the Screen.

For example like this:

```
var scr = Screen;
var userName = PXAccess.GetUserName();
var password = GetUserPassword();
var context = Screen;
var lgRes = context.Login(userName, password);
```

but I preserved user password between different sessions